# Why does $i\operatorname{Arg}(1+z)- i\operatorname{Arg}(1-z)$ lie in $(-\pi, \pi]$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Verify that the identity
>
> $\operatorname{Log}\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}=\operatorname{Log}(1+z)-\operatorname{Log}(1-z)$ holds when $|z|<1$.

Getting $\operatorname{Log}\Big(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}\Big) = \operatorname{Log}\Big|\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}\Big| + i\operatorname{Arg}\Big(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}\Big)$, we have that $i\operatorname{Arg}\Big(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}\Big)$ = $i\operatorname{Arg}(1+z)- i\operatorname{Arg}(1-z)$. So since $\operatorname{Arg}(1 \pm z)$ lies between $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, $i\operatorname{Arg}(1+z)- i\operatorname{Arg}(1-z)$ should be between $(-\pi, \pi]$ which is the principal branch. Is it enough to say that $i\operatorname{Arg}(1-z)$ and $i\operatorname{Arg}(1+z)$ can never lie on the same vertical chord of the open disk and so we will never get that the difference in arguments lies in $[-\pi,\pi ]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple proof goes like this: $\Re(\frac{1+z}{1-z}), \Re (1+z), \Re(1-z) >0$ for $|z|<1$, so the principal branch of the logarithm applies to each expression and gives 3 analytic functions on the unit disc. The required identity holds trivially for $z$ real between say $0$ and $1$ so it holds everywhere in the disc by the identity theorem for holomorphic functions. Then take imaginary parts to conclude.

Comment: Graphically, I'm thinking that adding a $1$ to $z$ shifts the disk to the right, and -$z$ switches $(x,y) $ to $(-x,-y) $, so adding $1$ has the same effect as shifting the first disk to the right by $1$ unit. But how would I go about proving that $\Re \dfrac {1+z}{1-z} $, $\Re (1+z) $, and $\Re (1-z) $ are $>0$ for $|z|<1$?

Comment: Let $z=re^{i\theta}, 0 \le r <1$. Then $Re({1 \pm z})=1 \pm r\cos\theta >0$, while $\Re \dfrac {1+z}{1-z} = \frac{1-r^2}{|1-z|^2} > 0$